How to Prevent Duplicate Logs in Log4j2 Configuration?
I’m working with a Log4j2 XML configuration and I’ve encountered an issue where duplicate logs are being written to the log files. I’m trying to prevent this duplication but am unsure of how to adjust my configuration to achieve this.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="WARN">

    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="fileAppender" fileName="log/application.log" filePattern="log/application.log.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%p{length=1} %d{yyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${LOG_FILE_SIZE}"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${BACKUP_INDEX}"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Routing name="routingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${mdcContext}">
                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has a value for mdc. The value dynamically determines the name of the log file. -->
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="dynamicFileAppender" fileName="log/application.${mdcContext}.log" filePattern="log/application.${mdcContext}.log.%i">
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <pattern>%p{length=1} %d{yyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} %m%n</pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${LOG_FILE_SIZE}"/>
                        </Policies>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${BACKUP_INDEX}"/>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
                <Route ref="fileAppender" key="$${mdcContext}"/>
            </Routes>

            <RollingFile name="allFileAppender" fileName="log/application.all.log" filePattern="log/application.all.log.%i">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%p{length=1} %d{yyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${LOG_FILE_SIZE}"/>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${BACKUP_INDEX}"/>
            </RollingFile>

            <RollingFile name="errorFileAppender" fileName="log/application.error.log" filePattern="log/application.error.log.%i">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%p{length=1} %d{yyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${LOG_FILE_SIZE}"/>
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${BACKUP_INDEX}"/>
            </RollingFile>

            <Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%p{length=1} %d{yyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} %m%n"/>
            </Console>

        </Routing>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.commons" level="INFO"/>
        <Logger name="org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool" level="INFO"/>
        <Logger name="org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread" level="INFO"/>
        <Logger name="org.quartz.core.JobRunShell" level="ERROR"/>
        <Logger name="com.example" level="ERROR"/>
        <Logger name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server" level="INFO"/>

        <!--
        <Logger name="example.scheduler" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="routingAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        -->

        <Root level="${LOGGING_LEVEL}">
            <AppenderRef ref="routingAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="allFileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" level="ERROR"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="errorFileAppender" level="ERROR"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>


Despite these efforts, logs are still being duplicated across the different log files. The same log entries appear in multiple files, which is not the desired behavior.
How to prevent duplicate logs.

Can you edit your question and explain what do you expect the configuration file to do? The effective behavior of your configuration is simple to explain: you sent all messages that pass the level filter to 2 appenders and those at least as severe as ERROR to all 4 appenders.

This file is running on live project and we are getting duplicate logs, So I want to prevent that duplicate logs
